# Clustering of nodes (MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic

I am currently attempting to create a cluster on MarkLogic and would like to ask if is there a need for a license to create the cluster? I managed to get Machine B to connect to Machine A but it begins a "Restarting MarkLogic Server to load new group configurations" and results in an error "ERROR: too many loops!".

I have tested with pinging and opening of the admin page via port 8001 from one machine to the other.

Both database is empty and do not have any type of license. For now I know that unfiltered geospatial search requires licensing, if anyone can let me know any other limitations due to licensing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s probably a hostname thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic uses a [number of ports](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/93/0/marklogic-server-ip-ports), not just 8001.  Make sure that 7997,7999, 8000, 8001, 8002 are accessible between the machines.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, make sure all hostnames can be resolved (either via DNS or /etc/hosts) on all systems.  Even if you add the system via IP, it will attempt to resolve the IP to a hostname, and the cluster creation process will use the hostname to complete the setup.

Comment: @Micheal Gardner, Thank you this solved my issue. But I would like to enquire on how data is loaded into this clusters, do I load data separately into each node manually? Or is marklogic able to manage and transfer data among the cluster itself so all I need to do is to load data into a single node?

Comment: @WhiteSolstice  Databases store the data in forests, and the data will be distributed where ever the forests are.  So if you have a database with forests on both hosts, it will automatically balance the data between the two hosts.

Comment: @Micheal Gardner, for marklogic to understand and balanced the data between certain forests/databases is there a certain requirement? Such as a need for the forest and database to share the same name or the XDBC server to share the same port number? Finally, I would like to ask, whether is there a way to increase data ingestion throughput? I attempted to do this by pumping data into all 3 nodes at once, but this resulted in an error on the two other nodes. So I returned to using  a single node for pumping data in, it's currently running at 100% of it's CPU used.

Comment: @WhiteSolstice - Getting too much for comments, so I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873551/how-data-is-loaded-and-managed-by-a-marklogic-cluster/55873552#55873552

Comment: Small comment on resolving hostnames via DNS: if that is difficult for whatever reason, consider using IPs themselves for hostnames inside ML admin ui, those don't need to be resolved.